# Performance of "all" in haskell

Tags: haskell

I got nearly no knowledge of haskell and tried to solve some Project Euler Problems. 
While solving [Number 5](http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=5) I wrote this solution (for 1..10)

```
--Check if n can be divided by 1..max
canDivAll :: Integer -> Integer -> Bool 
canDivAll max n = all (\x ->  n `mod` x == 0) [1..max]

main = print $ head $ filter (canDivAll 10) [1..]
```

Now I found out, that `all` is implemented like this:

```
all p            =  and . map p
```

Doesn't this mean, the condition is checked for every element? Wouldn't it be much faster to break upon the first False-Result of the condition? This would make the execution of the code above faster.

Thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`and` itself is short-circuited and since both `map` and `all` evaluation is lazy, you will only get as many elements as needed - not more.

You can verify that with a `GHCi` session:

```
Prelude Debug.Trace> and [(trace "first" True), (trace "second" True)]
first
second
True
Prelude Debug.Trace> and [(trace "first" False), (trace "second" False)]
first
False
```

Answer (score 4):

`map` does not evaluate all its argument before `and` executes. And `and` is short-circuited.

Notice that in GHC `all` isn't really defined like this.

```
-- | Applied to a predicate and a list, 'all' determines if all elements
-- of the list satisfy the predicate.
all                     :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Bool
#ifdef USE_REPORT_PRELUDE
all p                   =  and . map p
#else
all _ []        =  True
all p (x:xs)    =  p x && all p xs
{-# RULES
"all/build"     forall p (g::forall b.(a->b->b)->b->b) . 
                all p (build g) = g ((&&) . p) True
 #-}
#endif
```

We see that `all p (x:xs)    =  p x && all p xs`, so whenever `p x` is false, the evaluation will stop.

Moreover, there is a simplification rule `all/build`, which effectively transforms your `all p [1..max]` into a simple fail-fast loop*, so I don't think you can improve much from modifying `all`.

---

<sup>*. The simplified code should look like:</sup>

```
eftIntFB c n x0 y | x0 ># y    = n        
                  | otherwise = go x0
                 where
                   go x = I# x `c` if x ==# y then n else go (x +# 1#)

eftIntFB ((&&) . p) True 1# max#
```

Answer (score 4):

This is a good program for the fusion optimization, as all your loops are expressed as fusible combinators. Thus you can write it using, e.g. Data.Vector, and get better performance than with lists.

From N=20, with lists as in your program:

- 52.484s

Also, use `rem` instead of `mod`.

- 15.712s

Where the list functions become vector operations:

```
import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed as V

canDivAll :: Int -> Int -> Bool
canDivAll max n = V.all (\x ->  n `rem` x == 0) (V.enumFromN 1 max)

main = print . V.head $ V.filter (canDivAll 20) $ V.unfoldr (\a -> Just (a, a+1)) 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You're assuming that `and` is not short-circuiting.  `and` will stop execution on the first `false` result it sees, so it is "fast" as one might expect.

Comment: I don't think his problem is that he didn't realize that `and` short-circuits, but rather that he thought `map` would go through the whole list before `and` even runs (as would be the behavior in eager languages) because he doesn't understand/know about lazy evaluation.